# Sencha Touch and Leaflet.js API

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, leaflet

I would like to use Leaflet.js API with Sencha Touch 2.3.1 and leaflet.js gives this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Map container not found.
```

These links are included in index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js"></script>
```

Here is my mainview code:

```
Ext.define('App.view.Main', {

    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'main',
    requires: [
        'App.view.MapView',
    ],

    config: {
        layout: 'card',
        items: [
        {   
            itemId: 'mapview',
            xtype: 'mapview',
            id : 'map'
        }
        ]
    }
});
```

This is the 'App.view.MapView' code:

```
Ext.define("App.view.MapView", {
  extend: 'Ext.Container',
  requires: ['Ext.device.Geolocation'],
  xtype: 'mapview',
  initialize: function(){

          var map = L.map('map').setView([47.36865, 8.539183], 13);
          var layer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

          map.on('click', function() {
            console.log('Click-Event on map / Time: ' + Date.now());
          });

  },
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, seems I found a solution. I changed this line:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([47.36865, 8.539183], 13);
```

to

```
var map = L.map(this.element.dom).setView([47.36865, 8.539183], 13);
```

Comment: So it seems the id selector wasn't working... Weird. I wonder why.

Comment: I am trying to do like what is the answer, but the map doesnt appear. How Can I fix this?

Answer (score 13):

Leaflet is searching for a DOM element, `map`, that isn't there (yet...).

This problem occurs when `L.map('map')` is called before the DOM has finished loading.

Comment: It's not a matter of when the script are included, but when the map is initialized.

Answer (score 5):

Guessing the js was executed before the DOM was ready. Try wrapping your code in a function and setting window.onload equal to your function.